# how to use telerik gridcheckboxcolumn and keep checked when radgrid is bind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

How to use telerik gridcheckboxcolumn and how to keep checked rows when radgrid is bind , for example, when paeg changed , rows that checked is unchecked?

Comment: tanks .I dont test your answer. I use this solve: http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/transfer-selected-rows-from-one-gridview-to-another-in-asp.net.aspx

Comment: I no understand your Solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the checkbox column to a bit column in the database otherwise the status of the checkbox will be lost when  you leave the page. Make sure the checkbox column has the datafield bind to the relevant db column:

```
 <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="YourDataFieldInDB" DataType="System.Boolean".......
```